# WiX Managed Bootstrapper, calling BurnBootstrapper.Engine.Detect() multiple times

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I have inherited a existing product which utilizes a WiX Managed Bootstrapper Application whose behavior is a little suspect.  The logic within the bootstrapper calls `BurnBootstrapper.Engine.Detect()` multiple times prior to the plan phase of the installation.  Is this behavior correct? Logically it seems Detect should only be called once.  If Detect should only be called once, it there any harm in calling it multiple times besides the wasted clock cycles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time Detect is called, the Burn engine performs all searches and evaluates detect conditions.  There is no harm in calling it multiple times, though it doesn't really make sense to call it multiple times without something interesting happening between the calls (like user input or a significant amount of time where one of the products could have been installed in the meantime).